# multiselect listbox value placement

Tags: excel, vba

I need the values from a multi-select list-box to populate into different locations within a spreadsheet.  Each selection needs to populate on a different row i.e. 1st selection B60, 2nd selection B68, 3rd selection B78.

I tried adding the below code to what I have, but get "Without if" error and "Next For" error:
I tried adding:

```
If Me.ALLAC.Selected(x) Then
Ck = 2
addme = Me.ALLAC.List(x)
addme.Offset(8, 1) = Me.ALLAC.List(x, 1)
addme.Offset(8, 2) = Me.ALLAC.List(x, 2)
Set addme = addme.Offset(1, 0)
```

Below is the current code as written

```
Private Sub cmdAdd2_Click()
  'dimension the variable
Dim addme As Range
Dim x As Integer, Ck As Integer
  'set variables
Set addme = sheet9.Range("B59").Offset(1, 0)
Ck = 0
  'run the for loop
For x = 0 To Me.ALLAC.ListCount - 1
  'add condition statement
If Me.ALLAC.Selected(x) Then
Ck = 1
addme = Me.ALLAC.List(x)
addme.Offset(0, 1) = Me.ALLAC.List(x, 1)
addme.Offset(0, 2) = Me.ALLAC.List(x, 2)
Set addme = addme.Offset(1, 0)
  'clear the selected row
ALLAC.Selected(x) = False
End If
Next x
  'send a message if nothing is selected
If Ck = 0 Then
MsgBox "There is nothing selected"
End If
End Sub
```

I'd like to see each selection in the multi-select list to go to specific cells within my spreadsheet.

But they are showing up one row after the next.  i.e. B60, B61, B62.

Comment: hi. in the first exemple u need to add a end if at the end, but in the second i dont see any error

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Set addme=addme.offset (8,0) to move the second and third clicks down 8 rows from my first click.  Perfect, simple fix, no more code needed.  I was putting more into it then needed.  Thank you Pawel for your input.